# subprocess.Popen optional arguments

Tags: python, popen, argparse

I'm creating a python script that uses the arguments given by the user to start an executable:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', '--stringC', dest="stringC", help="stringC", type=str)
parser.add_argument('-f', '--stringF', dest="stringF", help="stringF", type=str)
parser.add_argument('-o', '--stringO', dest="stringO", help="stringO", type=str)
parser.add_argument('-d', '--stringD', dest="stringD", help="stringD", type=str)
parser.add_argument('-s', '--stringS', dest="stringS", help="stringS", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

command = 'executable-location'
statement = [command, '-c', stringC, '-f', stringF, '-o', stringO, '-d', stringD, '-s', stringS]
p = subprocess.Popen(statement)
```

The problem is that some of these parameters are optional for the executable and if not provided, the program uses its own default values. So currently all the parameters are used even though I want to use the default values sometimes.

Ideally, I only want to give the executable the arguments that were parsed. I have tried

```
statement = [command, args]
p = subprocess.Popen(statement2)
```

and

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

but it gives me the following error:

> TypeError: 'Namespace' object is not iterable

Hopefully someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution, if feasible, is to incorporate the program defaults into your parser.

```
# For example
parser.add_argument('-f', '--stringF', dest="stringF",
                    help="stringF", type=str,
                    default="-f's default)
```

Then you don't have to worry about whether or not to use `args.stringF` in the argument list.

Otherwise, you need to build the command list one option at a time.

```
statement = [command]
if args.stringF is not None:
    statement += ["-f", args.StringF]
# etc
```

Comment: Thank you, I decided to go with the second option as I don't want to have to update the script every time the default values of the program change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure as to what you are trying to do, but may be this will help:

define a parser, with 2 different kinds of default values:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('-f','--foo',default='FOO')
>>> parser.add_argument('-b','--bar',default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
```

Parse a case without any arguments.  Note that the resulting Namespace has a value for `foo` (which is the default), but none for `bar` - that's because of the `SUPPRESS` default.

```
>>> args=parser.parse_args([])
>>> print(args)
Namespace(foo='FOO')
```

`args.foo` will give the string 'FOO'.  But you can also convert the namespace to a dictionary, or to a list of tuples

```
>>> print(vars(args))
{'foo': 'FOO'}
>>> print(vars(args).items())
[('foo', 'FOO')]
```

If I give a couple of arguments the `args` namespace how has:

```
>>> args=parser.parse_args(['-f','val1','-b','val2'])
>>> print(args)
Namespace(bar='val2', foo='val1')
```

and the same dictionary and list conversion is possible.

```
>>> print(vars(args).items())
[('foo', 'val1'), ('bar', 'val2')]
```

It's your choice as to whether the `args` contains a reasonable default, or no value at all for arguments that the user does not give.  The default `default` is `None`, which also easy to test for (e.g. `args.baz is None`).

Constructing a simple list like

```
['command', 'foo', 'val1', 'bar', 'val2']
```

should be straight forward.  Using `-f` and `-b` instead of the default `dest` names will take a bit more fiddling.